# Try-Catch exception in XML

Tags: ant

While deploying SOA composites using *ant*, the deployment fails due to the following error:

> [echo]
>        [echo] ERROR IN TRYCATCH BLOCK:
>        [echo] /home/oracle/deploymentScripts/build.soa.xml:108: The following error occurred while executing this line:
>        [echo] /home/oracle/deploymentScripts/build.soa.xml:123: The following error occurred while executing this line:
>        [echo] /u01/oracle/middleware/Oracle_Home/soa/bin/ant-sca-package.xml:51: The following error occurred while executing this line:
>        [echo] /u01/oracle/middleware/Oracle_Home/soa/bin/ant-sca-compile.xml:342: Java returned: 1 Check log file : /tmp/out.err for errors
>        [echo]
>        [echo] **************************************************************
>        [echo] *
>        [echo] *  ANT TARGET NAME:            deployComposites
>        [echo] *  FAILED PROCESS:             UpdateGoNoGoApprovalCRMOD
>        [echo] ***

This is a part of the `buildsoa.xml` file.
I'm not actually getting what might be the error.
Kindly help me with this please.

Comment: @zx485 Please don't add comments explaining the edits you have done to a post. All it does is add "noise". (That information is available from the edit history anyway.) I suggest you delete them all.

Answer (score -1):

Check your Java home path in your .bat file, and make sure the Java home path is set correctly (please check your Java installation path in your system).
Also check the Java home path in the environment variables of your system.